# How do JavaScript for-loop work with a variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables

I am new to JavaScript and there’s something I am struggling to understand…

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i)
}
console.log(i);
```

Here’s a piece of codes and when I see this, right off the bat I thought the out put is going to be something like,

```
//0
//1
//2
//2
```

Since the for loop counts up to 2 and leaves the variable as 2, I thought the output will be 2 if I log it out after the for loop.
But the output was different from what I expected.. (instead of 2, it spits out 3 when it’s logged after the for loop)

```
//0
//1
//2
//3
```

I read the several articles and they do explain that the variable’s scope is global and that, but I still don’t get why I get 3 as an output.

(One of the articles I read: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/thrown-for-a-loop-understanding-for-loops-and-timeouts-in-javascript-558d8255d8a4/)

I'd really appreciate your help,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it for a moment, if `i` is `2` then the loop would still run because `2 < 3`. At the end of this loop when `i = 2` it will use `i++`, hence `i` is now `3`. And now the conditional fail because `3 < 3` is false, so it exits. Hence `i` remains `3`.

`3` is the first number on `i` that would abort the loop.

Comment: So the for-loop does actually increment the variable to 3, but it cease the following operation since the conditional fails (because 3 < 3 is false)? Oh wow thank you so much, I completely thought the for-loop stops counting up when the variable hits 2..!